# List of strings and ints in go?

Tags: go

I have no idea what I am doing and I decided to try out using a [list (docs)](http://golang.org/pkg/container/list/#New) in go. This is the most I can figure out

1. Why is %v printing `{0xf840024660 <nil> 0xf840023660 4}`?
2. Why am I not getting an error for mixing ints with strings?
3. How do I force a type? (such as ints only, strings only etc)

Code:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "container/list"

func main() {
    ls := list.New()
    ls.PushBack("a")
    ls.PushBack(4)
    ls.PushBack("5")
    fmt.Println(ls)
    ls2 := list.New()
    ls2.PushBack(4)
    ls2.PushBack(8)
    fmt.Printf("%v\naaa\n", *ls2.Front())
    fmt.Println(*ls2.Back())
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

First off, you probably don't want `container/list`. You're probably looking for something like slices and `append()`. For example:

```
x := []int { 1, 2, 3 }
x = append(x, 4)
x = append(x, 5, 6)
```

The reason `container/list` lets you mix types is that it uses `interface{}` to hold values, and any type satisfies the empty interface.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question for the calls to `Front()` and `Back()`, it is because you're printing out the [`Element` struct](http://golang.org/pkg/container/list/#Element) which does not contain printable values. If you want to print the `Element.Value` you have to do `(*ls2.Front()).Value`. Similar reasons are true for why `fmt.Println(ls)` is printing weird.